# Alignment of tikzpictures

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to put the equivalent sign between these two tikzpictures drawn with 
`schemabloc` package. This is the code I tried to make this work, but it gave me that. Any idea on how to make this work?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{e}
\sbBloc{a}{$a$}{e}
\sbRelier[$e$]{e}{a}
\sbBloc{b}{$b$}{a}
\sbRelier{a}{b}
\sbSortie{s}{b}
\sbRelier[$s$]{b}{s}
\end{tikzpicture}
$\iff$
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{e}
\sbBloc{a}{$ab$}{e}
\sbRelier{e}{a}
\sbSortie{s}{a}
\sbRelier[$s$]{a}{s}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Ideally it should compile  unless, of course, that is what you are asking about.

Comment: Edited my question accordingly. There are still more packages that I used that I didn't mention because they're irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to put the `$\iff$` inside your picture:

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \sbEntree{e}
    \sbBloc{a}{$a$}{e}
    \sbRelier[$e$]{e}{a}
    \sbBloc{b}{$b$}{a}
    \sbRelier{a}{b}
    \sbSortie{s}{b}
    \sbRelier[$s$]{b}{s}
    \node at (5.5,0) {$\iff$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \sbEntree{e}
    \sbBloc{a}{$ab$}{e}
    \sbRelier{e}{a}
    \sbSortie{s}{a}
    \sbRelier[$s$]{a}{s}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can set the `baseline` on the `tikzpicture` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \sbEntree{e}
    \sbBloc{a}{$a$}{e}
    \sbRelier[$e$]{e}{a}
    \sbBloc{b}{$b$}{a}
    \sbRelier{a}{b}
    \sbSortie{s}{b}
    \sbRelier[$s$]{b}{s}
  \end{tikzpicture}
    $\iff$
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \sbEntree{e}
    \sbBloc{a}{$ab$}{e}
    \sbRelier{e}{a}
    \sbSortie{s}{a}
    \sbRelier[$s$]{a}{s}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This requires a little tweaking:

[image]

Comment: I will be using this a lot in my document, so is there a more general way? Or some kind of method to evaluate​ the x-coordinate of the node. I don't think 5.5 will fit that nicely other cases.

Comment: You could put `\tikzset{baseline=(current bounding box.center)}
` at the top of your document and then all `tikzpicture` environments will be centered around their middle.

Comment: @MajdFreigi `\sbSortie{s}{b}` defines a `coordinate` named `s`, so you can do `\node [right] at (s) {$\iff$};` instead.